# Maven configuration for Android 3.0 using Library Projects and AspectJ

Tags: android, aspectj, maven-3

I've tried to find a solution for my problem but I haven't found it yet.

I'm working on a project that only compiles against Android 3.0, uses Android Library Projects, which are now supported by the maven-android-plugin and also uses AspectJ.

From maven-android-plugin website,
"The currently valid dependencies versions are 1.5_r4, 1.6_r2, 2.1.2 and 2.2.1"

I want to create a Maven 3 configuration for a project in this conditions.
Any hints?

I'm using maven-android-plugin 3.0.0-alpha-7.

Comment: What maven android plugin version are you using? apklib is supported since 2.9.0-beta-1, see [ApkLib](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib) and [Changelog](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [sample](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples) provided by maven-android-plugin that you can start with (you need LibraryProjects in 2.9.0-beta download), btw, the website is out of date, I am using 2.3.3 in my current project.

Comment: I've used the samples for the 3.0.0-alpha-7 version but those don't include an example using AspectJ.